# Terminate connection by sending some text

Tags: unix

Is it possible to terminate an established `tcp`connection created with `netcat` sending some text from host to server or viceversa?

I attach what I'm asked to do:

[image: Snapshot]

Comment: It depends on the application protocol being used. Why not just kill netcat?

Comment: @RogerLipscombe thanks for replying! unluckily, it's a requirement to close the connection using text...

Comment: Dig deeper. Find out why and explain why "it's a requirement" to use text, because (on the face of it, and until we understand your use-case better) it's a stupid requirement.

Comment: there should be a comma between "send some text from each machine" and "and terminate the connection". Those are seperate instructions.

Comment: @Frank Thomas if so, that would mean that i could use the "kill" command?

Comment: well, that would cause the remote port to hang. Ctrl + D sends an EOF to the IO stream between both hosts, so that the TCP connection can be torn down. Otherwise the remote port will continue to think the connection exists until it times out or sends traffic to the source host, which would be rejected.

Answer (score 0):

Many people use `Ctrl + D` to [close a netcat connection](http://earthwithsun.com/questions/687494/netcat-should-i-use-ctrlc-to-close-the-connection).

To teardown a TCP connection `netcat` would have to send the FIN sequence, so that both endpoints know that the circuit is closed. Since the teardown sequence is driven by TCP flags, its not as simple as sending a string. You would have to use netcat options to generate this kind of traffic explicitly.

1. You send a FIN.
2. they send an ACK to your FIN, and a FIN of their own.
3. You ACK their FIN.
4. Connection is closed at both ends.

So, using Ctrl + D seems the best bet.

Comment: thanks for replying! As I replied above, it's requirement to send text to close the connection... I was thinking about sending manually the FIN flag but I don't know how to do it...

Comment: I'm afraid your requirement cannot be met using the tools you specify. The remote application would have to be crafted to listen for that string, and to start the tear down process when it receives it. application data (the data region of the TCP segment) cannot affect TCPs state, period. Netcat, because of its goal of abstracting away TCP/IP details, does not allow you to specify the details of packets; its all about streams, since it acts as the entirety of the network stack below the application. its like Sockets-in-a-box.

Comment: Are you connecting to a well known service like FTP? FTP will recognize the string `byebye` as a disconnection verb. If you are hitting such a service, let us know which one it is and we may be able to help further.

Comment: There is nothing in what you provided that mandates that you must send text to close the connection.    I think you misunderstand the task specifications.